# How to fetch Logical volume information in Linux?

Tags: linux, go, filesystems, lvm

I am working on a assignment where i have to fetch logical volume information from Linux . This information includes name , description , used space and total space . lvdisplay can display the logical volume but is there any other way to fetch the info ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `lvs` instead of `lvdisplay`

`lvs` lists all logical volumes within its name,size and volume group among each other.